# Inserting CSV or dict data in DB using cx_Oracle Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, oracle, oracle-autonomous-db

I am running the below code to insert CSV data into oracle DB.
code executes fine till generating the CSV file.

```
DEFAULT_CONFIG = "~/.oci/config"
DEFAULT_PROFILE = "DEFAULT"
config_file="config.json"
atp_dict_data=[]

db_username = "xx"
db_password = "xx"
db_type = "xx"

class DbConnect(object):
    comp_db_map = {}
    cx_Oracle.init_oracle_client(lib_dir="./instantclient_19_8")
   
    def __init__(self, db_username, db_password, db_type):
        self.db_username = db_username
        self.db_password = db_password
        self.db_type = db_type
        self.pool = cx_Oracle.SessionPool( db_username, db_password, db_type,min=1,max=10,increment=0,encoding='UTF-8')
    
    def get_connection(self):
        return self.pool.acquire()
    
    def select_from_db(self):
        sql = ('SELECT * FROM TT.PMP WHERE TE = "sall"');
        connection=self.get_connection()
        with connection.cursor() as cursor:
            cursor.execute(sql)
            connection.commit()
        return "executed"

    def insert_csv_data(self):
        //not sure how to insert data from csv

def config_file_parser(config_file):
    global atp_dict_data
    ab=[]
    config=configparser.ConfigParser()
    config.read(config_file)
    profile=config.sections()
    for config_profile in profile:
        func1 = get_work_request(file=config_file, profile_name=config_profile)
        #get_print_details(func1)


def get_work_request(file=DEFAULT_CONFIG, profile_name=DEFAULT_PROFILE):
    global oci_config, identity_client, work_request_client, atp_dict_data
    oci_config = oci.config.from_file(file, profile_name=profile_name)
    identity_client = oci.identity.identity_client.IdentityClient(oci_config)
    core_client = oci.core.ComputeClient(oci_config)
    db_client= oci.database.DatabaseClient(oci_config)
    atp_db_details = db_client.list_autonomous_databases(oci_config["compartment"]).data
    json_response = json.loads(str(atp_db_details))
    for i in json_response:
        
        atp_dict_data.append({'region': oci_config["region"], 'atp_name': i["db_name"], 'ser':oci_config["ser"], 'm_start': i["m_start"], 'm_end': i["m_end"]})
    
    print(atp_dict_data)
    keys = atp_dict_data[0].keys()
    with open('test.csv', 'w') as output_file:
        dict_writer = csv.DictWriter(output_file, keys)
        dict_writer.writeheader()
        dict_writer.writerows(atp_dict_data)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    config_file_parser(config_file)
    atp_conn = DbConnect(db_username, db_password, db_type)
    atp_conn.__init__
    atp_conn.get_connection
    atp_conn.select_from_db
```

Problems :

1. when I am calling Dbconnect class it doesn't even execute it just executes till `atp_conn.__init__` and stops.
2. How do I insert CSV data files into Oracle DB? Is there any better approach like without generating the CSV file and inserting data directly by reading from dict (`atp_dict_data`)using instaclient connection.

Any help would be great

Comment: Since you have the data in Python variables, you should not write to disk as a CSV file and then read that file back - that would be inefficient.  Just put the data in the format needed  by`executemany()` as shown in [Batch Statement Execution and Bulk Loading](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/batch_statement.html).  Without knowing your table schema I can't give more detail.

Comment: Some side comments: (i) use a fixed size connection pool, see [connection pool sizing](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/connection_handling.html#connection-pool-sizing) (ii) don't call commit after a SELECT since that adds extra, unnecessary overhead.

Comment: @ChristopherJones Thanks, problem is I do not know how to put that data into format as you mentioned , my data out here is dict data as you can see. what details u need for my schema ? Its a table with 5 columns A,B,C,D,E with all varchar2(255) values

Comment: @ChristopherJones Along with that ,  wanted to also understand that if I call the functions class of DB connect class why it does not executes

Comment: Check out the cx_Oracle batch loading examples and see how they work.  The last example in the doc I linked to shows how to insert into 2 columns. I guess you'd change your `atp_dict_data.append` line, and remove all your CSV code.  If you have problems, update your question with examples of data.  Make it easy for us  by giving the SQL to create the table.  I suggest you start a new question for the DB connection class question and give a simplified (runnable) example.

Answer (score 0):

I think you only have to add a code similar to the one I show you below and encapsulate it into your function.

**Keep in mind that below is just an example, you have to adapt it to your specific code**

Easiest way using `csv`

```
import cx_Oracle
import csv

con = cx_Oracle.connect('hr/hrpsw@localhost/orcl')
cur = con.cursor()
with open("mycsvfile.csv", "r") as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter='|')
    # skip first line if header row
    next(csv_reader)
    for lines in csv_reader:
        cur.execute(
            "insert into table (field1, field2, ..... , fieldn ) values (:1, :2, ..... , :n)",
            (lines[0], lines[1], lines[2], ....., lines[n]))

cur.close()
con.commit()
con.close()
```

Using `pandas`

```
import pandas as pd
import cx_Oracle 

my_data = pd.read_csv('mycsvfile')
my_data.head()

from cx_Oracle import DatabaseError
try:
    conn = cx_Oracle.connect('yourconnectiondetails')
    if conn:
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        for i,row in my_data.iterrows():
            sql = "INSERT INTO table (field1, field2, ..... , fieldn ) values (:1, :2, ..... , :n)"
            cursor.execute(sql, tuple(row))
        # the connection is not autocommitted by default, so we must commit to save our changes
        conn.commit()
        print("Record inserted succesfully")
except DatabaseError as e:
    err, = e.args
    print("Oracle-Error-Code:", err.code)
    print("Oracle-Error-Message:", err.message)
finally:
    cursor.close()
    conn.close()
```

Comment: Got the idea on how to insert the csv , but how do I call the class DB connect in my existing code ?
I would like to place the csv insert code inside the Dbconnect class under `def insert_csv_data(self):`
As u can see I am parsing the config file and that runs in loop `    for config_profile in profile:
        func1 = get_work_request(file=config_file, profile_name=config_profile)` so can't afford to place in same function
thats the reason I thought of creating a class named Dbconnect so that I can execute it seperately

Comment: This example should not be followed - it should be updated. Use `executemany()` not `execute()`.  The former is a lot faster.  The cx_Oracle documentation has an example in [Batch Statement Execution and Bulk Loading](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/batch_statement.html)